# file_exists not working for a file present in a file server

Tags: php, windows-7, file-io, fileserver

I am facing a issue such that i am able to link to a file that is present in an http server or a ftp server.. but i am not able to link to a file that is present in a file server..

ie, More Clearly..
if the URL is `http://serverpath.com/images/image.jpg` or `ftp://serverpath.com/images/image.jpg` or a remote path the `file_exists` function gives a `true` value  but if a give a file server path like the similar path as `//serverpath/public/images/image.jpg` the `file_exists` function is giving a `false` value.

**UPDATE**

I am using PHP 5.4.4

There was a bug reported regarding this issue in the previous version of php ie below 5.3 and it was told that this issue has been solved in the versions above 5.3. Is there any change in the php.ini that we need to make change to enable. I searched but did not get the answer i expected

Please Help

Comment: Is that a windows share?

Comment: yea a windows 7 share...

Comment: @AsishAP:-yup.as always....have the answer.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http:\\www.somesite.com\somefile.html'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

curl_exec($ch) will return FALSE if no file is present or the actual data on success

However:

You'd better bind your shared folder to a logical hard drive with

```
net use E: \\servername\shareddirectory
```

doing this will allow you to access your remote file as it were on a local disk (say E:).

file_exists() should work if you give the "local" path E:\filepath\filename

Comment: I just gave u a example with image  I need to check if a file exists it might be a text file or html file.

Comment: Tip: if your answer includes "@" you're doing it wrong. That's better :) EXCEPT - you can't use curl to access a file on a network share

Comment: here my edit.. please check the solution before downscoring, thanks!

Comment: If i give a file server link in the above code the result will be the error number 6. And I don't think creating a drive for that particular network path and giving the path name is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Your php.ini allow_url_fopen is on?

Comment: yes it is.that parameter is on but that url parameter is for http and ftp only na however its already working